# The futex facility returned an unexpected error code on VS Code with WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working on a project using Visual Studio Code in Windows and WSL (Ubuntu 18.04). It compiles and runs fine but when I try to debug the application and step over/into it just aborts with the message **The futex facility returned an unexpected error code** a bunch of times in the terminal. I ruled out an implementation issue because if I run the project in a Ubuntu VM (no cross compile, everything in Linux) I can debug the program as expected.

Can someone point me to where to start investigating this issue? I rather use VS Code in Windows and avoid the VM because of it just lags terribly.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: Windows 10 Version 1809 build 17763.1039.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you hit [a known bug in the futex syscall implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3618) in WSL. It was fixed in the [Windows 10 November 2019 Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) (builds 18277 and higher).

Comment: I am on 18362 and started getting this Futex error since today, so there must be some new issue

Comment: @Razz Yikes. Can you share a backtrace/stack when the app crashes? Should see a call to futex_fatal_error() in there.

Comment: I'll try to find some time to upgrade and see if that helps.